# Crash using Metal buffers

Tags: multithreading, macos, metal

I use a background thread to create Metal buffers:

```
var vertices:UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>?=nil
var indexes:UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>?=nil
var vertexCount: UInt32=UInt32()
var indexCount: UInt32=UInt32()

triangulatePoints(hull, &vertices, &indexes, &vertexCount, &indexCount)

defer {
    free(vertices)
    free(indexes)
}

if let vertexBuffer=device.makeBuffer(bytes: vertices!,
                                      length: Int(vertexCount)*MemoryLayout<Float>.size*3,
                                      options: .storageModeShared),
   let indexBuffer=device.makeBuffer(bytes: indexes!,
                                     length: Int(indexCount)*MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size,
                                     options: .storageModeShared) 
{
   metalObject=MetalObject(vertices: vertexBuffer, indices: indexBuffer)
}
```

The `MetalObject`s are temporarily stored in a dictionary and later accumulated in arrays and the array is returned. This happens from within a dispatch queue (number #5 in the Debug stack trace below):

```
CustomOperationQueue.sharedInstance.addSerialOperation {
    //This calls the device.makeBuffers() and stores them in a dictionary owned by the image
    image.constructMetalBuffers(withPrecision: precision, device: device)
    //The MetalObjects are accumulated in arrays. Sorted by their draw type, such as instanced or not. One array of each type.
    let metalLayer:MetalImageLayer=image.layerWithDelegate(device: device, delegate: self)

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
        //The MTKView delegate observes this property and triggers a redraw when it changes 
        self.metalLayer=metalLayer
    }
```

The `MetalObject`s are simple containers, which are also stored in other containers:

```
class MetalObject: NSObject {
    var vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer
    var indexBuffer: MTLBuffer

    init(vertices: MTLBuffer, indices:MTLBuffer) {
        vertexBuffer=vertices
        indexBuffer=indices
    }
}

class MetalImageLayer: NSObject {
    var layers=[MetalPolarityLayer]()
}

class MetalPolarityLayer: NSObject {
    var elements=[MetalObject]() //For general objects that need to be drawn piece by piece
    var regions=[MetalObject]() //For region objects that can be instanced
}
```

In Debug mode, I often get crashes on the line `metalObject=MetalObject(vertices: vertexBuffer, indices: indexBuffer)` with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40dedeadbec8)`. The stack trace looks like:

```
#0  0x000000010166a6e2 in swift_unknownRetain ()
#1  0x000000010005bf5f in StrokeLine.constructMetalBuffers(withPrecision:device:) at Image+Metal.swift:445
#2  0x000000010005c8b2 in @objc StrokeLine.constructMetalBuffers(withPrecision:device:) ()
#3  0x0000000100050b4d in Image.constructMetalBuffers(withPrecision:device:) at Image+Metal.swift:40
#4  0x0000000100051082 in @objc Image.constructMetalBuffers(withPrecision:device:) ()
#5  0x0000000100067eef in closure #1 in WindowLayer.observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context:) at WindowLayer.swift:181
```

Inspecting the `vertexBuffer` from the debugger then gives: `po vertexBuffer
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2e7466697770).`

On the other hand in Release mode, I sometimes get crashes on

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff60084fce __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff601c2150 pthread_kill + 333
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff5ffe132a abort + 127
3   com.apple.IOAccelerator         0x00007fff5279a1ea ioAccelResourceListAddNewGroupAndResource + 221
4   com.apple.IOAccelerator         0x00007fff52799d19 IOAccelResourceListAddResource + 304
5   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver 0x00007fff32aa02ef IGBufferMemory<31ul>::listId(unsigned int) + 85
6   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver 0x00007fff32aa654b ShaderBindingStage::updateUAVTable(unsigned int, unsigned int, bool) + 459
7   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver 0x00007fff32a9fe0d ShaderBindingStage::updateBindingTableData() + 1631
8   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver 0x00007fff32a9f70b ShaderBindingStage::writeTableIf() + 55
9   com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver 0x00007fff32a9cc11 IGAccelRenderCommandEncoder::programPipeline(sPrimitiveData const&) + 4685
10  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver 0x00007fff32a9b7b4 IGAccelRenderCommandEncoder::drawIndexedPrimitives(MTLPrimitiveType, unsigned int, MTLIndexType, MTLIGAccelBuffer*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) + 710
11  com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsMTLDriver 0x00007fff32a9b40c -[MTLIGAccelRenderCommandEncoder drawIndexedPrimitives:indexCount:indexType:indexBuffer:indexBufferOffset:] + 324
```

No further information is logged about what might cause the crash.

Using Instruments to find Zombies gives no results.

How should I go about finding out what goes wrong here?

Comment: What's the code for `MetalObject`? What's the stack trace for the crash of debug builds? What line of your code does it occur within? What are `vertices` and `indexes`? How are the `MetalObject`s sent to the main thread?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking into my problem. I've added a lot of information. I hope this is what you need.

Comment: So, what's the code at Image+Metal.swift:445, which is the line apparently provoking the crash. Also, I assume `triangulatePoints()` is allocating space for the `vertices` and `indexes`, right?

Comment: That code is `metalObject=MetalObject(vertices: vertexBuffer, indices: indexBuffer)`, so it's the last line from the first piece of code I copied.

Comment: The triangulate function allocs using malloc, e.g.: `*vertices=(float *)malloc(G.number_of_nodes()*sizeof(float)*3);`

Comment: So, that looks like (Objecitve-)C++. I don't know Swift nor its bridging to C well enough, but is it possible that's where the problem lies?

Comment: I doubt it. I've been using this code for about half a year now and the problem only appeared this week since I've been generating a lot more buffers. Some entities were drawn using the tessellation engine, but as I wanted to support El Capitan I added code to draw entities using 'normal' triangles as well. This is when the problem started. It also wouldn't explain that in Release mode it seems to crash on the `drawPrimitives...` call.